# apply function to pandas column based on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Imagine I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{'source_id': '1', 'source_desc': 'XML1'},
 {'source_id': '2', 'source_desc': 'XML2'},
 {'source_id': '3', 'source_desc': 'XML3'}]
```

Now I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
di = [{'source_id': '1','city':'NY'},
       {'source_id': '2','city':'Santiago'},
       {'source_id': '3','city':'Berlin'}]
dff=pd.DataFrame(di)
dff
```

Now I want to add a column source_desc based on the previous collection of dictionaries.
I tried:

```
dff['source_desc'] = dff['source_id'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: d['source_desc'] for d in di if d['source_id'] == x)
```

I dont understand why this does not work.

EDIT:
desired output would be a pandas df like:

```
desired = [{'source_id': '1','city':'NY','source_desc': 'XML1' },
       {'source_id': '2','city':'Santiago','source_desc': 'XML2'},
       {'source_id': '3','city':'Berlin','source_desc': 'XML3'}]
desired_df=pd.DataFrame(desired)
desired_df
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Avoid apply, it is quite slow and not recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes a generator and you need `next`:

```
dff['source_desc'] = dff['source_id'].apply(lambda x: next((y['source_desc'] for y in d if y['source_id'] == x)))
```

---

```
>>> dff
  source_id      city source_desc
0         1        NY        XML1
1         2  Santiago        XML2
2         3    Berlin        XML3
>>>
```

Comment: why do you need next. I.e why it falls without it?

Comment: @JFerro Well, Other wise it gives a generator object... You need the first value.

Answer (score 2):

Just dataframe and merge. Code below

```
dff.merge(pd.DataFrame([{'source_id': '1', 'source_desc': 'XML1'},
 {'source_id': '2', 'source_desc': 'XML2'},
 {'source_id': '3', 'source_desc': 'XML3'}]), how='left', on='source_id')
```

Output

```
    source_id      city source_desc
0         1        NY        XML1
1         2  Santiago        XML2
2         3    Berlin        XML3
```

Answer (score 2):

Better if you let pandas handle the read method, then just use a `merge` method.

```
source_json = [{'source_id': '1', 'source_desc': 'XML1'},
 {'source_id': '2', 'source_desc': 'XML2'},
 {'source_id': '3', 'source_desc': 'XML3'}]

df = dff.merge(pd.json_normalize(source_json), on=['source_id'])

  source_id      city source_desc
0         1        NY        XML1
1         2  Santiago        XML2
2         3    Berlin        XML3
```

Comment: why do you use json_normalize and dont pass the list as such? Thanks. (Just curious)

Comment: @JFerro Pandas is highly vectorized, so its core methods are written in `c` or in other words, in such a way to compliment speed. Core python isn't as fast and when doing things like `loops` or creating `generators` you're dealing with one row at a time, which will be a lot slower. you can also pass in the `path` to `json_normalize` play around with the library, lots of cool stuff in there :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) like below:

```
>>> dct = [{'source_id': '1', 'source_desc': 'XML1'},{'source_id': '2', 'source_desc': 'XML2'},{'source_id': '3', 'source_desc': 'XML3'}]

>>> di = [{'source_id': '1','city':'NY'},{'source_id': '2','city':'Santiago'},{'source_id': '3','city':'Berlin'}]
>>> dff=pd.DataFrame(di)
>>> dff
    source_id   city
0          1    NY
1          2    Santiago
2          3    Berlin

>>> pd.merge(dff, pd.DataFrame(dct), on="source_id")

    source_id   city    source_desc
0          1    NY          XML1
1          2    Santiago    XML2
2          3    Berlin      XML3
```